# How to read in excel files from a folder and join them into a single df?

Tags: python, pandas

First-time poster here! I have perused these forums for a while and I am taken aback by how supportive this community is.

My problem involves several excel files with the same name, column headers, data types, that I am trying to read in with pandas. After reading them in, I want to compare the column 'Agreement Date' across all the data-frames and create a yes/no column if they match. I then want to export the data frame.

I am still learning Python and Pandas so I am struggling with this task. This is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob


xlpath = "/Users/myname/Documents/Python/"

# read .xlsx file into a list

allfiles = glob.glob(xlpath + "*.xls")

# for loop to read in all files

for excelfiles in allfiles:
    raw_excel = pd.read_excel(allfiles)

# place all the pulled dataframe into a list

list = [raw_excel]
```

From here though I am quite lost. I do not know how to join all of my files together on my id column and then compare the 'Agreement Date' column? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

THANKS!!

Comment: How exactly you want to compare the "Agreement Date" values is not clear to me, can you explain further or give an example? What does "match" mean? Are all DataFrames always the same number of rows and you want to check if all values in same order in the column "Agreement Date" are equal?

Answer (score 0):

1. In your loop you need to hand the looped value and not the whole list to read_excel
2. You have to append the list values within the loop, otherwise only the last item will be in the list
3. Do not overwrite python builtins such as `list` or you can encounter some difficult to debug behaviors

Here's what I would change:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

xlpath = "/Users/myname/Documents/Python/"

# get file name list of .xlsx files in the directory
allfiles = glob.glob(xlpath + "*.xls")

# for loop to read in all files & place all the pulled dataframe into a list
dataframes_list = []
for file in allfiles:
    dataframes_list.append(pd.read_excel(file))
```

You can then append the DataFrames like this:

```
merged_df = dataframes_list[0]
for df in dataframes_list[1:]:
    merged_df.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

Use ignore_index if the Indexes are overlapping and causing problems. If they already are distinct and you want to keep them, set this to False.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. However, I am a little confused at how I would then go about comparing the 'Agreement Date' column if I am appending my files on top of one another?

Comment: Yeah, so the question is whether you even need to join all the dataframes into one. If your only goal is the comparison you should probably work from within the list. But I'm still not sure what you mean by "match". Perhaps what you really want is just a meta-dataframe listing all your dataframes and which of them "match"?

Comment: Yes, on second thought, there actually is no reason to join them. From the list of data frames, I am just trying to compare the aforementioned date column and see whether the dates are identical across each data frame. 

Apologies, for my miscommunication, I am still learning how to properly explain coding problems.